# Prometheus - How to reuse a filtered series to speed up query time?

Tags: prometheus

Now I'm using **Prometheus** as Time series DB. I want to **reuse a filtered series** to optimize the query time.

Now I have a time series `command_stat{id="x",host="x.x.x.x"}`, example:

```
command_stat{id="0",host="10.x.x.1",stat="requests"}
command_stat{id="0",host="10.x.x.2",stat="requests"}
command_stat{id="1",host="10.x.x.1",stat="requests"}
command_stat{id="1",host="10.x.x.2",stat="requests"}
command_stat{id="2",host="10.x.x.1",stat="requests"}
command_stat{id="2",host="10.x.x.2",stat="requests"}
...
```

I have about **10000 commands** and about **500 command id**

I'll calculate the total of rate on each command id, which is:

```
sum(rate(command_stat{stat="requests"}[5m])) by (id)
```

And I should **compare** this value with values in the **last 15 days**. Example, I'll calculate:

```
sum(rate(command_stat{stat="requests"}[5m] offset 1d)) by (id)
sum(rate(command_stat{stat="requests"}[5m] offset 2d)) by (id)
sum(rate(command_stat{stat="requests"}[5m] offset 3d)) by (id)
...
sum(rate(command_stat{stat="requests"}[5m] offset 15d)) by (id)
```

I should also calculate **mean** and **standard deviation** from 15 values.
With *mean*, I can use `avg(...) by (id)` and for *standard deviation*, I can use `stddev(...) by (id)`

Example for *standard deviation*, that should be:

```
stddev (
  label_replace(sum(rate(command_stat{stat_name="requests"}[5m] offset 1d)) by (id), "time", "1d", "", ".*") or
  label_replace(sum(rate(command_stat{stat_name="requests"}[5m] offset 2d)) by (id), "time", "2d", "", ".*") or
  ...
  label_replace(sum(rate(command_stat{stat_name="requests"}[5m] offset 15d)) by (id), "time", "15d", "", ".*")
) by (id)
```

The query time is **too slow**, I want to speed up by checking only command id with the condition:

```
sum(rate(command_stat{stat="requests"}[5m])) by (id) > 1000
```

After this condition, the number of commands that should be checked is only about **40**. I want to calculate *mean* and *standard deviation* only on the ~**40** commands.

Can you help me optimize this problem? I think we can reuse the `command_stat` series after filter by above condition.

Answer (score 0):

I've missed [**recording rules**](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/) in Prometheus. I think I can use this feature to pre-compute the series:

```
sum(rate(command_stat{stat="requests"}[5m])) by (id)
```

And then I can calculate *mean* and *standard deviation*.

If you have a better solution, please let me know to improve.

Thanks!!